# Proof similarity of complex power series

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Let be the functions

$$
f(x)=\sqrt{2}\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{4}-\frac{1}{2}\arctan(x))}{(1+x^2)^{1/4}} \qquad g(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}
$$

Obviously, they are holomorphic functions in a neighborhood of $0$. The series of $g(z)$ is well known and using Mathematica we have

$$
f(x)= 1+\frac{x}{2}- \frac{3x^2}{8}-\frac{5x^3}{16}+\frac{35x^4}{128}+\frac{63x^5}{256}-\frac{231x^6}{1024}-\frac{429x^7}{2048}+\dotsc
$$
$$
g(x)= 1+\frac{x}{2}+ \frac{3x^2}{8}+\frac{5x^3}{16}+\frac{35x^4}{128}+\frac{63x^5}{256}+\frac{231x^6}{1024}+\frac{429x^7}{2048}+\dotsc
$$

**Exercise**. Proof the absolute value of the coefficients of the two series are the same.

**Attemp**. With trigonometric manipulation I get
$$
f(x)=\frac{1+x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{2}(1+x^2)^{3/4}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}}}
$$
My idea is use the Cauchy Integral Theorem to calculate the coefficients 
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
$$
and with changes of variables get something that seems to
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{g(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz
$$ 
But if I work in $\mathbb{C}$ I need to define $\log(1+z^2)$ and work with it in changes of variables doesn't look so friendly.

Can you give me a hint to prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $\phi(z)=\sum_k a_k z^k$.

The first step is to see how to express $a_0+a_1 z-a_2 z^2 -a_3 z^3 +a_4 z^4+\ldots$ using $\phi$.

The four roots of $X^4=1$ being $\lbrace \pm 1, \pm i \rbrace$. You have to solve the system:
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&i&-i&-1\\1^2&i^2&(-i)^2&(-1)^2\\1^3&i^3&(-i)^3&(-1)^3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a\\ b \\c \\d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\-1 \\-1 \end{pmatrix}$$

As the solutions are $a=d=0$, $b=\frac{1-i}{2}, c=\frac{1+i}{2}$ you obtain:
$$a_0+a_1 z-a_2 z^2 -a_3 z^3 +a_4 z^4+\ldots = \frac{1}{2} \left((1-i)\phi(ix)+(1+i)\phi(-ix) \right)$$

---

Here you then have to prove that near $0$:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{1-ix}}+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{1+ix}} \right)$$

Using your expression of $f$ this is the same to prove that near $0$:
$$(1+i) \sqrt{1-ix}+(1-i) \sqrt{1+ix}=\sqrt{2}\frac{1+x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+x^2}}}=2\sqrt{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$
which seems easier.

Comment: Your idea seems good, but I don't see your last chains of equalities. Is it true that $\sqrt{1-iz}\sqrt{i+iz} = \sqrt{1+z^2}$ in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: For the LHS:
$$\left(\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{1-ix}}+\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{1+ix}} \right)=\frac{(1+i) \sqrt{1-ix}+(1-i) \sqrt{1+ix}}{\sqrt{(1+ix)(1-ix)}}$$
and for the other:
$$\left(1+\sqrt{1+x^2} \right)\left(x+\sqrt{1+x^2} \right)=x+(1+x^2)+(1+x)\sqrt{1+x^2}=(1+2x+x^2)/2+(1+x^2)/2+(1+x)\sqrt{1+x^2}=1/2 (1+x+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2$$
If you need I can write more details in the answer.

Comment: I'm scared of complex square root. Like in my last question, in $\mathbb{C}$, $\sqrt{1+x^2}^2 = 1+x^2$?

Comment: If I am not mistaken as $\sqrt{1-iz} \sqrt{1+iz}$ and $\sqrt{1+z^2}$ are both holomorphic functions near $0$ and are the same on $i \Bbb R$ then they are the same (near $0$).

Comment: The same argument can be used to show that near $0$, $\sqrt{1+x^2}^2=1+x^2$.

Or you can write the series of the functions and check that they are the same.